# How to know what "they" refer to in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning

> The Swedish Crown brought in a law which required at least half the
> mayors and councillors to be nativeborn, but there is every indication
> that this law was ignored.
> However, the councils looked after the interests of the merchants and
> guaranteed that **they** would adhere to their contracts. (bolds by me)
>
> - A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

1. What does the "they" refer to in the sentence? To councils or to merchants? And how do you decide that matter in sentences like this?
2. These two sentences comes back to back in the book. I can not understand why the author used the word "however" in the second one. Because it does not have any interpretation that negates to former one.

Comment: The actual *words* are ambiguous. Native Anglophones are no better equipped than you to decide whether the councils are guaranteeing that ***they the councils*** will adhere to "their" contracts, or that ***the merchants*** will  adhere to the contracts. Come to that, it's ambiguous whether those are the council's contracts or the merchants contracts (if one can meaningfully distinguish those two possibilities). It's even possible that ***they*** refers to one party, and ***their*** refers to the other (the council will force merchants to abide by contracts entered into by those merchants).

Comment: I won't closevote the question, even though it's basically POB. But I *will* downvote any answer that tries to assign a specific referent to ***they*** or ***their*** in the cited context. I see no meaningful answer other than "It's ambiguous", but I can't see the point in posting that as an Answer.

Comment: For me, "the councils looked after the interests of the merchants and [the councils] guaranteed that they [the councils] would adhere to their contracts" also refers to the councils. **Because** the councils looked after the interests of the merchants and [the councils] guaranteed that the *merchants* would adhere to their contracts. *would not make much sense*. The councils, presumably, have no way to guarantee the merchants would adhere to contracts.  However, the councils could guarantee that they the councils would adhere to their own contracts with merchants.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I want to translate this sentence into my language and my language dont have such opportunity to put down this exact same meaning in exact same 'ambiguity'. And as a matter of fact the author did referred something right? And thats why I'm here in this forum for learning the answer of this question from native speakers. I don't see any point in downvoting any answer and I think that this is against the whole point of this forum if there will not be any answers.

Comment: The point of the forum is to help people learn English. Actually deciding what "they" and "their" refer to here isn't really part of knowing English - it's just a matter of deciding which interpretations make most sense. I haven't looked at it that closely, but I assume the contracts being referred to here are between the councils and the merchants, so it's not really meaningful to ask whether "their" contracts refers to either party in particular. But you must decide yourself whether the councils are making promises about their own behaviour, or what they will force the merchants to do.

Comment: You should contact the author and ask him to explain. Rather than us.

Comment: @Lambie - maybe ask Tim Geddes, who translated _Finlands Historia_ into English from the original Swedish?

Comment: I should think that a sensible thing for someone translating a scholarly work like this would be to read around on the subject. That is, provide oneself with some measure of understanding of the background. There is plenty of stuff about the Hanseatic League around. A good translator does more than just transpose the words before them from one language to another in a purely language exercise.  A quick dip into the original Swedish version might be an idea? I am not suggesting that there is a danger of 'English as She is Spoke' from translating a translation, but still...

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with English usage, but with a knowledge of Finish law during whatever historical period this was. The key is knowing enough context to understand what "contracts" refers to.  E.g. (and I'm not saying this is true) perhaps council is elected by the merchants, with a formal contract defining exactly what the mayor will do during his tenure and at what pay. And perhaps the federal law was proposing removing some mayors and councillors from office.  If all that were true, then the meaning of the sentence would have been clear to the author. But we don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

"The Swedish Crown brought in a law which required at least half the mayors and councillors to be nativeborn, but there is every indication that this law was ignored. However, the councils looked after the interests of the merchants and guaranteed that they would adhere to their contracts."

The point is that the law ("which required at least half the mayors and councillors to be nativeborn") was being ignored. However, some councils, which favored the merchants, were ready to stand by some current contracts anyway.

Unfortunately, this quote doesn't give us a clear link between the contracts and the afore-mentioned law nor between "the councils" and the other parties. If the original quote included these links, I think the passage would be clearer.